# Import multiple pdf files to database (filename = value in other column)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, image, pdf

Im trying to make a script that imports multiple pdf-files to a database.
I got this far - a specific file:

```
DECLARE @pdf VARBINARY(MAX)

SELECT @pdf = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Users\jd\Desktop\Invoiceimage\999999.pdf', SINGLE_BLOB) AS image;

SELECT @pdf, DATALENGTH(@pdf)

INSERT INTO dbo.CustomerInvoiceImage(InvoiceImage, CustomerInvoiceId) VALUES(@Pdf, '13') 
GO
```

It works beautiful. Now I need the script to take more than one file and also to identify the filename and insert it to "CustomerInvoiceId" instead of the specific number 13.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Perhaps SQL Server?)

Comment: Sorry! SQL server

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script. You need to enable/disable `xp_cmdshell` only if necessary. A better solution could be create a stored procedure with `@Folder` as parameter.

```
/*
-- enable xp_cmdshell
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
*/

DECLARE @Folder AS VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @Folder = 'C:\Users\jd\Desktop\Invoiceimage'

DECLARE @Files AS TABLE(Name VARCHAR(MAX))

DECLARE @shellCommand AS VARCHAR(1024)
SELECT @shellCommand = 'DIR ' + @Folder + '\*.pdf /A-D /B'

INSERT INTO @Files(Name)
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @shellCommand

DECLARE @Name AS VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE C_Files CURSOR FOR
    SELECT Name
    FROM @Files
    WHERE Name IS NOT NULL

OPEN C_Files
FETCH NEXT FROM C_Files INTO @Name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    DECLARE @CustomerInvoiceId AS INTEGER
    SELECT @CustomerInvoiceId = CAST(LEFT(@Name, CHARINDEX('.', @Name) - 1) AS INTEGER)

    EXEC ('DECLARE @File AS VARBINARY(MAX); '+
        'SELECT @File = BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N''' + @Folder + '\' + @Name + ''', SINGLE_BLOB) AS IMAGE; ' +
        'INSERT INTO CustomerInvoiceImage(InvoiceImage, CustomerInvoiceId) VALUES(@File, ' + @CustomerInvoiceId + ');'
    )

    FETCH NEXT FROM C_Files INTO @Name

END

CLOSE C_Files
DEALLOCATE C_Files

/*
-- disable xp_cmdshell
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 0
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
*/
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a spin!

Comment: I get this message:

Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'C:\Users\jd\Desktop\Invoiceimage\1.pdf' to data type int.

Is the problem that we are trying to take more than the number and insert it into customerinvoiceid?

Comment: sorry, now I understand what you mean: you need to extract number from file name. answer update but not tested.

Comment: NOW:  
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 27
Incorrect syntax near 'CAST'.

Comment: I LOVE YOU. Thanks a million